# Application removal and APNS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, uninstallation

How to avoid sending push notification to iOS app that is uninstalled.

Is there any way that we can catch application uninstallation event and call our server to stop sending notification.

What happens to the notification that is sent to device after the app is uninstalled.

Will old and new notification be available in the notification center even after the app is uninstalled.

Please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The APNS Feedback Service exists for this purpose. When you connect to this service, you receive device tokens of devices that uninstalled your application, and you should stop sending push notifications to such device tokens.

When you send a notification to a device that uninstalled the app, Apple logs the device token and will send it to you the next time you contact the Feedback Service.

Comment: Apple will send it to me next means ... After uninstallation if install the app again ...i will get the queued up notifications huh

Comment: @sathishkumar_kingmaker I don't think you will get any queued up notifications if you re-install, since Apple will discard such messages once it detects the app is uninstalled.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: my question : will the notification is delivered even app is uninstalled ? .in this case i am not using " Feedback Service".  Expain ?

Comment: @MuraliMohan It will reach the device, which will detect that the app has been uninstalled, and inform the APN server about it. It won't be displayed to the user. If you are not using the feedback service, you'll have no way of knowing the app was uninstalled. All this is true for the old API. I believe there is a new API that reports uninstalled apps when you try to send notifications to them without using the feedback service, but I don't know much about this new API.

Answer (score 2):

When you call the APNS service ,you will receive uninstalled app's device tokens.
After that checking those device token, you should stop sending push notifications to those device tokens.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @sathishkumar_kingmaker enjoy coding ;-)